# $anchorScroll effect with mouse scroll instead of click in angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, scroll, anchor-scroll

I've been looking but I couldn't find an answer/solution so far, so I hope that someone here is able to answer me and guide me to an solution if this is possible.

I'm trying to achieve the result seen in the second example of this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll , but instead of clicking in links I need to be able to use the mouse scroll to navigate between anchors, i.e., if I scroll down I move one anchor down and if I scroll up I move one anchor up.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you in achieving your requirement [angular-scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/).
You can also use Bootstrap [scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).